# How to add 1 milliseconds to a datetime string?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, varchar

Based on a select, I can return x rows like this:

```
1   2019-07-23 10:14:04.000
1   2019-07-23 10:14:11.000
2   2019-07-23 10:45:32.000
1   2019-07-23 10:45:33.000
```

We have all milliseconds with 0.

Is there a way to add 1 by 1 milliseconds, so the select would look like this:

```
1   2019-07-23 10:14:04.001
1   2019-07-23 10:14:11.002
2   2019-07-23 10:45:32.003
1   2019-07-23 10:45:33.004
```

I'm trying to create a cursor or even a update with no success.

This is the query to get the results I want:

```
  select top 10 ModifiedOn 
    from [SCHEMA].[dbo].[TABLE]
  where FIELD between '2019-07-23 00:00' and '2019-07-23 23:59'
```

There are 81k values. The field is `DATETIME`.

Comment: Are you trying to add 1 millisecond to row 1, 2 milliseconds to row 2, 3 milliseconds to row 3, etc.?

Answer (score 34):

`Datetime` is not precise to the level of 1 millisecond. What you are asking for is not possible unless you change to a different datatype (i.e. `datetime2`).

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Important quote:

> Accuracy  Rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds

Answer (score 13):

The `DateAdd` function is what you are looking for.

Use `millisecond` as the first parameter to the function, to tell it that you are adding milliseconds. Then use `1` as the second parameter, for the number of milliseconds to add.

Here is an example, grabbing the current time into a variable, and then adding one millisecond to it and saving the result as a second variable, and then printing each variable

```
Declare @RightNow as DateTime2
Declare @RightNowPlusAMillisecond as DateTime2

Select @RightNow = Getdate()
Select @RightNowPlusAMillisecond = DateAdd(millisecond,1,@RightNow)

Print @RightNow
Print @RightNowPlusAMillisecond
```

Results:

```
2019-07-23 08:25:38.3500000
2019-07-23 08:25:38.3510000
```

Note:

As Forrest points out in [another answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/243543/22336), the `datetime` data type does not guarantee millisecond precision. It rounds to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds. If you want millisecond precision, use `datetime2`.

Answer (score 13):

[@Doug-Deden](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/243536/22336) has the right starting point, but I just wanted to try to answer what I thought was the original intention of the question - how to apply it to a result set with increasing milliseconds per row.

In that case, you can use [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and a [Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (edit as needed for you table structure, including joins, etc.).

Select to show values:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT t.my_id, t.my_date_column, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY my_date_column, my_id DESC) AS R
FROM Table1 t
)
SELECT TOP 1000 *, DATEADD(MILLISECOND, R, CAST(my_date_column AS datetime2)) [new_date]
FROM CTE
ORDER BY my_date_column
```

Update joins back to original table:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT t.my_id, t.my_date_column, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY my_date_column, my_id DESC) AS R
FROM Table1 t
)
UPDATE t SET 
my_date_column = DATEADD(MILLISECOND, R, CAST(my_date_column AS datetime2))
FROM CTE c
     JOIN Table1 t ON c.my_id = t.my_id
```

Comment: This CTE is updatable. No need to join back to `Table1`. Just do `UPDATE CTE SET my_date_column =...`

Answer (score 4):

I have done it using `DATETIME2(3)`.

As you can see on the query below, it is more `economic`:

```
declare @dt1 datetime2(3)
declare @dt2 datetime2

SELECT @DT1 = SYSDATETIME()
SELECT @DT2=  SYSDATETIME()

SELECT [THE LENGTH OF DATETIME2]=DATALENGTH(@DT2)
      ,[THE LENGTH OF DATETIME2(3)]=DATALENGTH(@DT1)
```

[image]

The differences between `datetime` and `datetime2` are well explained [here](https://sqlhints.com/2011/09/17/difference-between-datetime-and-datetime2-datatype/).

For this exercise 
I create a temp table for testing purposes, and populate it with 999 different `random dates` from `01-jan-2019` and today (`23-july-2019`)

and then in order, I set the milliseconds from 1 to 999

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
SET NOEXEC OFF

IF OBJECT_ID ('TEMPDB..#T1') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #T1

CREATE TABLE #t1(the_date DATETIME2(3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED )
GO

-- run this 999 times - hopefully there will be no duplicates
-- SELECT 204*24*60*60 - today is 23-july-2019 - the 203rd day of the year
    DECLARE @DT DATETIME2(3)
    SELECT @DT = CONVERT(DATETIME2(3),
           DATEADD(SECOND, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 17625600), 
                   '2019-01-01'),120) 

    --SELECT @DT

    IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM #T1 WHERE THE_DATE = @DT) 
    INSERT INTO #T1 VALUES (@DT)
GO 999


--check it out what we have
SELECT * FROM #T1

--get the date and the new date
SELECT 
 THE_DATE
,THE_NEW_DATE= DATEADD(MILLISECOND, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY THE_DATE), THE_DATE ) 
 FROM #T1
```

and this is what I get: (partial view)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[One of the other posters](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/243543/22336) is correct; `DATETIME` (in T-SQL) is not accurate to the millisecond (it is accurate to the centisecond).

For that level of accuracy, you want to use `DATETIME2`.

Here is an example of converting a string `datetime` to `datetime2`, 
then adding 1 millisecond, and lastly, converting back to a string.

```
select convert(
            varchar(MAX), --in T-SQL, varchar length is optional
            dateadd(
                millisecond,
                1,
                convert(
                    datetime2,
                    '2019-07-23 12:01:23.11'
                )
            )
        )
```

Comment: [Please don't specify `varchar` without length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).